# Display image from an ASP.NET server in react client

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a react frontend and an ASP.NET Web API backend. The users have the ability to save their profile picture onto the server, but when I want to display those pictures from the frontend in an src attribute, it doesn't work.

In the controller I assign the `pictureUrl` like this and save it in the database:

```cs
user.PictureUrl = $"{Request.Scheme}://{Request.Host}/Images/{pictureUrl}";
```

In the frontend I fetch the user data along with its picture URL which is: https://localhost:44332/Images/018e4228-7b54-488f-b303-bfb881422dc7.jpg

and I try to display it in an avatar:

```js
const pictureUrl='https://localhost:44332/Images/018e4228-7b54-488f-b303-bfb881422dc7.jpg'; //Example (it is fetched from the server)
<Avatar
      src={pictureUrl}
      size={130}
      radius='md'
 />
```

Why does this not work? Can you help me achieve this by only providing the url without making a separate call to the api in order to fetch the file?

Side note: the image DOES GET UPLOADED TO THE SERVER AND THEREFORE EXISTS in the `Images` folder

Answer (score 0):

I figured that I needed to add this in the Program.cs file :

```cs
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Images")),
    RequestPath = "/Images"
});
```